# Count on multiple tables mysql with same identificator

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to do some counts on four tables, I am struggling doing it !

Here are my table script (4 simple tables, same tables)

```
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
  `id` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `TableA` (`id`, `zone`) VALUES
(1, 'ca'),(2, 'ca'),(3, 'fr'),(4, 'ca'),(5, 'ca'),(6, 'fr');

CREATE TABLE `TableB` (
  `id` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `TableB` (`id`, `zone`) VALUES
(1, 'ca'),(2, 'it'),(3, 'de'),(4, 'ca'),(5, 'it'),(6, 'fr');

CREATE TABLE `TableC` (
  `id` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `TableC` (`id`, `zone`) VALUES
(1, 'ca'),(2, 'ma'),(3, 'fr'),(4, 'pl'),(5, 'usa'),(6, 'fr');

CREATE TABLE `TableD` (
  `id` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `TableD` (`id`, `zone`) VALUES
(1, 'ca'),(2, 'pl'),(3, 'it'),(4, 'pl'),(5, 'ca'),(6, 'it');
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT Zone,
    TableAa,
    TableBb,
    TableCc,
    TableDd 
    FROM
    (  
            SELECT DISTINCT Ta.zone AS Zone,
                   COUNT(  Ta.id  ) AS TableAa,                     
                   COUNT(  Tb.id  ) AS TableBb,                    
                   COUNT(  Tc.id  ) AS TableCc,                    
                   COUNT(  Td.id  ) AS TableDd
              FROM TableA Ta
            LEFT JOIN TableB Tb ON Ta.zone = Tb.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableC Tc ON Ta.zone = Tc.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableD Td ON Ta.zone = Td.zone
            GROUP BY Ta.zone          
      UNION              
            SELECT DISTINCT Tb.zone AS Zone,
                   COUNT(  Ta.id  ) AS TableAa,                     
                   COUNT(  Tb.id  ) AS TableBb,                    
                   COUNT(  Tc.id  ) AS TableCc,                    
                   COUNT(  Td.id  ) AS TableDd
              FROM TableB Tb
            LEFT JOIN TableA Ta ON Tb.zone = Ta.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableC Tc ON Tb.zone = Tc.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableD Td ON Tb.zone = Td.zone
            GROUP BY Tb.zone          
      UNION              
            SELECT DISTINCT Tc.zone AS Zone,
                   COUNT(  Ta.id  ) AS TableAa,                     
                   COUNT(  Tb.id  ) AS TableBb,                    
                   COUNT(  Tc.id  ) AS TableCc,                    
                   COUNT(  Td.id  ) AS TableDd
              FROM TableC Tc
            LEFT JOIN TableB Tb ON Tc.zone = Tb.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableA Ta ON Tc.zone = Ta.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableD Td ON Tc.zone = Td.zone
            GROUP BY Tc.zone          
      UNION              
            SELECT DISTINCT Td.zone AS Zone,
                   COUNT(  Ta.id  ) AS TableAa,                     
                   COUNT(  Tb.id  ) AS TableBb,                    
                   COUNT(  Tc.id  ) AS TableCc,                    
                   COUNT(  Td.id  ) AS TableDd
              FROM TableA Td
            LEFT JOIN TableB Tb ON Td.zone = Tb.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableC Tc ON Td.zone = Tc.zone
            LEFT JOIN TableA Ta ON Td.zone = Ta.zone
            GROUP BY Td.zone  
          ) A
ORDER BY Zone              
    ;
```

I have some results, but incoherent results.

I should have

```
  zone   |   TableAa   |   TableBb   |   TableCc   |   TableDd
  fr     |   2         |   1         |   2         |   0
  ca     |   4         |   2         |   1         |   2
  it     |   0         |   2         |   0         |   2
  de     |   0         |   1         |   0         |   0
  ma     |   0         |   0         |   1         |   0
  pl     |   0         |   0         |   1         |   2
  usa    |   0         |   0         |   1         |   0
```

Instead, I have

```
  zone   |   TableAa   |   TableBb   |   TableCc   |   TableDd
  ca     |   16        |   16        |   16        |   16
  ca     |   32        |   32        |   32        |   32
  de     |   0         |   1         |   0         |   0
  fr     |   4         |   4         |   4         |   0
  fr     |   8         |   8         |   8         |   8
  it     |   0         |   4         |   0         |   4
  ma     |   0         |   0         |   1         |   0
  pl     |   0         |   0         |   2         |   2
  usa    |   0         |   0         |   1         |   0
```

The result are completely false, I really don't know why ! Here is an SQL Fiddle for testing : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cc0ab/3

Any help is needed.

Thanks.

PS : I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the code a bit and calculate each sum separatly and then join on the list of zones.

```
 SELECT T.ZONe,IFNULL(A.TableAa,0) AS TableAa,IFNULL(B.TableBb,0) AS TableBb,IFNULL(C.TableCc,0) AS TableCc,IFNULL(D.TableDd,0) AS TableDd
 FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT Ta.zone AS Zone
            FROM TableA Ta
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT Tb.zone AS Zone
            FROM TableB Tb
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT Tc.zone AS Zone
            FROM TableC Tc
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT Td.zone AS Zone
            FROM TableD Td
     ) T       
     LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT Zone, COUNT(*) AS TableAa FROM TableA GROUP BY Zone
       ) A 
       ON A.Zone=T.ZOne
     LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT Zone, COUNT(*) AS TableBb FROM TableB GROUP BY Zone
       ) B 
       ON B.Zone=T.ZOne
       LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT Zone, COUNT(*) AS TableCc FROM TableC GROUP BY Zone
       ) C 
       ON C.Zone=T.ZOne
       LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT Zone, COUNT(*) AS TableDd FROM TableD GROUP BY Zone
       ) D 
       ON D.Zone=T.ZOne
    ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cc0ab/19)